# I don't know how to add integers and print them in my blackjack game, C

Tags: c, integer, blackjack

I'm almost done with my blackjack game but I have problem with adding the cards integers. As you can see I print the cards and the value of card one is shown, the second value is the sum of both cards. I just want to print the sum but for some reason I can't get rid of the first cards value. And the dealer don't get a sum of his cards, why?

The second problem I have is that when one of the players gets a new card I want that new card value to be added to the first sum for that player.

```
void deal(const Card * const Deck, int value, int size, int size_1, int size_2){

    int i, j, length;
    char anotherCard[2];
    char name1[30];
    char name2[30];
    int valueName1 = 0, valueName2 = 0, valueDealer = 0;

    printf("Name player one > ");
    scanf("%s", name1);
    printf("Name player two > ");
    scanf("%s", name2);

    printf("\nWelcome %s and %s, lets begin!\n\n", name1, name2);
    getchar();

    printf("%s's card:\n", name1);
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
        printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
        valueName1 += Deck[i].value;
        printf("\nvalue > %d", valueName1);
    }

    //Name2 deleted
    //Dealer deleted

    printf("\nDo %s want another card? Y/N > ", name1);
    fgets(anotherCard, sizeof(anotherCard), stdin);
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n");

    length = strlen(anotherCard);
    for (j = 0; j < length; j++){

        if (strcmp(anotherCard, "Y") == 0 || strcmp(anotherCard, "y") == 0){
            for (i = 6; i < 7; i++){
                printf("%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
                valueName1 = Deck[i].value;
                printf("value > %d", valueName1);
            }
        }
        else
            break;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: "get rid of the first cards value". What does that mean exactly and why does it need to be done? Also, please do not post output as images but rather as text in your question. And it would help if you point out precisely what is wrong with that output (e.g what is the expected output).

Comment: You should add `\n` after `\nvalue > %d` so that the next card is printed on a line of its own.

Comment: I think its looking better now? If we take Marcus's card as an example.
hearts of six has value 6 but I don't want that to be printed at all. Only the sum and is shown as value > 16
later when marcus get one new card, diamonds of three I want that value > 3 to be added to the first value, (value > 16)

Comment: I don't see where your function is printing the dealer's cards.

Comment: sorry, I deleted that so I don't print to much code, I wrote that as commentary

Comment: **Do not post images of text!**

Comment: Sorry @Olaf I'm new here. It won't happen again

Comment: It still happens. Please use the `edit` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to print the final total, move that `printf` line outside the loop. You should also start the `printf` for each card with `\n` so that the cards will be shown on separate lines.

```
printf("%s's card:\n", name1);
for (i = 0; i < size; i++){
    printf("\n%5s of %-8s%c", Deck[i].decks, Deck[i].suits, (i + 1) % 2 ? '\t' : '\n');
    valueName1 += Deck[i].value;
}
printf("\nvalue > %d", valueName1);
```

Comment: Awesome! that worked. But how do I add the new card that Marcus gets to the first value? I want to add value > 3 to value > 16

Comment: Every time you give him another vard, you do `valueName1 += Deck[i].value;` just like in the loop.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing a loop like `for(i = 6; i < 7; i++)`. That will always loop just once, so what's the point?

Comment: I have had a lot of problem with this program. Now I have 3 different functions, one fillDeck, one shuffle and one deal. That for loop just mean that it starts giving card 6 from the array. Maybe a bad way to do it but it works. Thanks for the help, it solved the problem.

Comment: You can just assign `i = 6` instead of using a loop.